# Spring mvc- dropdown box options from database

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jdbc

This is what I implemented for create dropdown box using spring mvc.
This is working. But I need to get all the children belongs to `motherID="M-1"` in database records. This gives me only the first child which belongs to M-1.

Where I have to fix?  I'm a beginner for spring mvc.

## my_children.jsp

```
<form method="post" >
            <div class="div_box">
                <select id="child_name" name="Child Name" >
                    <option value="top">Select your child</option>
                    <option value="">${firstName} ${lastName}</option>

                </select>
                    <br>
            <div align ="justify">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success active">View Details</button>
           </div>
            </div>
    </form>
```

## controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/my_children", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void viewMyChild(ModelMap modelMap) {
    ChildNameAccess childNameDAO = new ChildNameAccess();
    try{
        Child child = childNameDAO.getChildDataByMotherId("M-1");


        modelMap.addAttribute("firstName",child.getFirstName());
        modelMap.addAttribute("lastName",child.getLastName());
    }

    catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

## dataAccess class

```
package com.emidwife.web.models.dataAccess;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.emidwife.web.models.entities.Child;
import com.emidwife.web.models.utilities.Database;


public class ChildNameAccess {
    private Database connection = new Database();
    Child child = new Child();

    public Child getChildDataByMotherId(String motherID) throws SQLException {
        connection.openConnection();
        try{
            ResultSet resultSet = connection.getData("SELECT * FROM childdetails WHERE MotherID=\'" + motherID + "\'");
            resultSet.next();
            //child.setChildId("1");
            child.setMotherId(resultSet.getString("MotherID"));
            child.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("FirstName"));
            child.setLastName(resultSet.getString("LastName"));
            //child.setDateOfBirth(resultSet.getDate("DOB"));

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            connection.closeConnection();
        }

        return child;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is not with spring mvc. You must do correct select statement from database. If you want to get all children by 'M-1' you can make following changes in your dataAccess class.

```
package com.emidwife.web.models.dataAccess;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.emidwife.web.models.entities.Child;
import com.emidwife.web.models.utilities.Database;


public class ChildNameAccess {
    private Database connection = new Database();

    public List<Child> getChildDataByMotherId(String motherID) throws SQLException {
        connection.openConnection();
        List<Child> children = new ArrayList<Child>();
        try{
            ResultSet resultSet = connection.getData("SELECT * FROM childdetails WHERE MotherID=\'" + motherID + "\'");
            while(resultSet.next()){
            Child child = new Child();
            child.setMotherId(resultSet.getString("MotherID"));
            child.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("FirstName"));
            child.setLastName(resultSet.getString("LastName"));
            children.add(child);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            connection.closeConnection();
        }

        return children;
    }
}
```

And also you must change your controller like following.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/my_children", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void viewMyChild(ModelMap modelMap) {
    ChildNameAccess childNameDAO = new ChildNameAccess();
    try{
        List<Child> children = childNameDAO.getChildDataByMotherId("M-1");

        modelMap.addAttribute("children ",children);
    }

    catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And jsp:

```
<form method="post" >
            <div class="div_box">
                <select id="child_name" name="Child Name" >
                    <option value="top">Select your child</option>
                    <c:forEach items="${children}" var="child">
                    <option value="">${child.firstName} ${child.lastName}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
                    <br>
            <div align ="justify">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success active">View Details</button>
           </div>
            </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: In controller  for this line `List<Child> children = childNameDAO.getChildDataByMotherId("M-1");` it give error 'The type List is not generic. It cannot be parameterized with argument <Child> '. what's that error? I tried to solve by importing java.util.List but at that point it identifies it as unused import

Comment: Did you change `getChildDataByMotherId` method?

Comment: I did all the changes you suggested.

Comment: Please check which List class did you imported. It must be java.util.List

Comment: i import this `import java.util.List ;`  It shows me this list import is collide with another statement.

Comment: `List<Child>` change to `java.util.List<Child>`

Comment: Thanks. It's solved. But dropdown Box has not taken values we pass. I'm working on it

Comment: I think you must add `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>` to your jsp for using JSTL.

Comment: If my answer help please upvote and accept as answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127705/discussion-between-hasini-silva-and-afsun-khammadli).